# To what extent is VALIS autobiographical?

Tags: valis

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick#Paranormal_experiences_and_mental_health_issues) and various other popular biographical sketches of Philip K Dick, at least some of the events of his novel *VALIS* correspond to real life experiences. Specifically, the information about his son's critical health issue.

Are there any sources beyond *VALIS* itself that confirm that the surgery event actually happened?

What, if anything, else in *VALIS* corresponds to verifiable autobiographical events?

Comment: Great question. The Exegesis referenced in VALIS is a real book that Dick wrote up until the end of his life. It is 8000 pages and has been released as an abridged 800 page version. I hope someone with the time fully answers this question!

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the Exegesis. However, I'm interested in sources other than Dick himself.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to an interview with Tessa Dick where she confirms the story:
[An interview with Tessa Dick](http://www.dickien.fr/dossiers/tessadick/interview-tessa-dick.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great Documentary called "Philip K Dick: The Penultimate Truth"

https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/philip_k_dick_the_penultimate_truth/

It's mostly interviews with people he knew personally (Including Tessa Dick). It delves into the surgery events where he supposedly had the theophany which inspired the Valis works.

This answer is mainly in response to the question "Are there any other sources...?" in case anyone would be interested.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please clarify if and how this is a source that the question is looking for.